# exit a bash script from a command substitution

Tags: bash

Is it possible to exit a script from a function that is called using command substitution?

e.g

```
#/bin/bash
function do_and_check()
{
    ls $1 || exit
}

p=$(do_and_check /etc/passwd)
q=$(do_and_check /xxx)
```

the result of running this is

```
bash -x yyy                                                                                                             
++ do_and_check /etc/passwd                                                                                                                  
++ ls /etc/passwd                                                                                                                             
+ p=/etc/passwd
++ do_and_check /xxx
++ ls /xxx
ls: cannot access /xxx: No such file or directory
++ exit
+ q=
+ echo /etc/passwd
/etc/passwd
```

I would have liked the exit to take me out of the script, not out of the command substitution. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
p=$(do_and_check /etc/passwd)
```

is executing a subshell, and that's what you're exiting from. I would set the exit value in your function (to a non-zero value), and then check the return value `$?` after the command substitution.

Comment: +1. Or, use `set -e` to have the script exit on *any* non-zero return status.

Comment: adding a $? check after each call to the function is what I want to avoid in the first place. `set -e` is too encompassing. I can call directly e.g. `do_and_check xxx` and have it set a _known_ variable ala perl's $_; or pehraps do_and_check could kill its parent?